# Visual Studio 2013 C# Page Inspector error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, page-inspector

I am new in .NET and C# and have started my new, first ASP.NET MVC5 project. I follow this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started
And have a problem with Page Inspector. When I create some file with .cshtml extension like these one that Visual Studio has created for me I recieve an error like this (about 2-3 times one by one, and when I close Visual Studio it also appears just once):

[image: Error]

It says in polish: (PL-ENG)

Przeglądarka sieci web  - Web Browser

Nie można odnaleźć - cannot find

Upewnij się, że ścieżka lub adres internetowy jest poprawny. - Make sure, that the path or internet address is correct.

I cant help myself with this, any suggestions? Appreciate your help!

Comment: I would say that you're trying to access a page that doesn't exist.

Comment: I did right click on the page in Visual Studio, so it must exist @PauloMorgado

Comment: And the path on the picture points to directory where Visual Studio is installed, but I don't know actually where accurately

Comment: The page should not be where Visual Studio is installed. If you have your project there, it's on the wrong place. The project should be on your user area.

Comment: no no, my project is under aproperly direction, i were talking about the path on the error(in the picture)